# Limit number of rows in the Detail section per page

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Report 8.0, how do I make a report show five rows on every page?

Answer (score 10):

Used to work for me... but not sure if it works with Crystal Reports 8.

To make it show 5 records per page do the following

1. Open the report in Design View
2. Right click on the Details section and select Section Expert
3. Make sure the Details section is selected in the Section Expert dialog box. 
   Check the box that says “New Page After”
4. Click the formula editor button to the right of the checkbox.
5. Enter the following formula: `Remainder (RecordNumber, 5) = 0`
6. Click Save and Close and then click OK.
   If you run the report it should break after each 5 rows.

Comment: I'm also not sure about CR8, but in more recent versions there is also an option to just enter the number of visible records you would like to page break on (In same spot, 'Section Expert' -> 'Paging' tab)

Answer (score -1):

In crystal report To Limit number of rows in the Detail section per page. I followed this steps

1)Open the report in Design View.
2)Right click on the Details section and select Section Expert .

After following this steps in  Details section it is showing Two Parts
 1)End of section 2)Visible Records.

so how to limit the number of rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [take a look at here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering. Please describe your answer adding with some more details.